How to get main Graphics Card using OSHI
I am using OSHI to include the device details in my game's logs. However, the issue is that using
new SystemInfo().getHardware().getGraphicsCards()

returns all the graphics cards
Graphics Card 1:
 Graphics Card Name:Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000, VideoController1
 Graphics Card Vendor: Intel Corporation
 Graphics Card VRAM: 2.0 GB
 Graphics Card Version Info: 10.18.10.5059

Graphics Card 2:
 Graphics Card Name:Intel(R) HD Graphics 530, VideoController2
 Graphics Card Vendor: Intel Corporation
 Graphics Card VRAM: 1.0 GB
 Graphics Card Version Info: 26.20.100.7870

Graphics Card 3:
 Graphics Card Name:NVIDIA GeForce GT 520, VideoController3
 Graphics Card Vendor: NVIDIA
 Graphics Card VRAM: 2.0 GB
 Graphics Card Version Info: 23.21.13.9135

Graphics Card 4:
 Graphics Card Name:NVIDIA GeForce GT 640, VideoController4
 Graphics Card Vendor: NVIDIA
 Graphics Card VRAM: 2.0 GB
 Graphics Card Version Info: 27.21.14.5671

I know that my main graphics card is NVIDIA GeForce GT 640, however considering that these logs would be sent by others, this "knowledge" won't really be useful. So how can I get the main graphics cards.
Also why do I have 4 graphics cards? to my knowledge HD Graphics 4000 are my integrated graphics and NVIDIA GeForce GT 640 is the graphics card I installed, I do not have any extra graphics cards.
Here is an MRE you can run to check yourself
import java.util.List;

import oshi.SystemInfo;
import oshi.hardware.GraphicsCard;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<GraphicsCard> graphcisCards = new SystemInfo().getHardware().getGraphicsCards();
        
        int graphicsCardNumber = 1;
        for(GraphicsCard graphicsCard : graphcisCards) {
            System.out.println("Graphics Card " + graphicsCardNumber + ":\n" + format(graphicsCard));
            graphicsCardNumber++;
        }
    }
    
    private static String format(GraphicsCard graphicsCard) {

        double memoryAsGB = graphicsCard.getVRam() / 1073741824;
        String string = "";
        
        string += " Graphics Card Name:" + graphicsCard.getName() + ", " + graphicsCard.getDeviceId() + "\n";
        string += " Graphics Card Vendor: " + graphicsCard.getVendor() + "\n";
        string += " Graphics Card VRAM: " + memoryAsGB + " GB\n";
        string += " Graphics Card Version Info: " + graphicsCard.getVersionInfo() + "\n";
                
        return string;
    }
}


[edit] the question and add a [mre].

OSHI maintainer here.  OSHI does not distinguish between "primary" or "main" cards. Some OS's/hardware use different graphics cards dynamically: for example macOS / Apple Hardware have "automatic graphics switching" and may use the integrated or discrete graphics based on Battery settings.  As for the second question, the answer is OS dependent, but OSHI is just providing data that your OS is reporting.  Feel free to open an issue at github to further diagnose this, but there's not enough information in this post to answer here.

@aled included the MRE

Maybe in the past you have installed drivers for old graphics cards in your OS?

@DanielWiddis Ive opened a issue on github with a lot more information :D

@aled yes ive mentioned it all here

OSHI maintainer here.
For the first question, it's not clear what "main" means in this context as some operating systems can have multiple graphics cards active, switching between them based on power management / battery saving needs, so the intent of OSHI is to list all the cards.
OSHI does not (yet) collect information to match up the graphics card list collected from the registry to the Device Manager display which shows only one card.  As you've noted in the comments, you've opened up an issue at the project site to find out how OSHI can filter it better.
I'll update this answer once that change is released.
